# VB.NET Windows Forms - How to prevent code from running after form.close?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a code where i open a form (form2) from a click in form1, and i iterate through a list...
if i have a specific condition, i want to close the form2...
however even if i close the form with 'me.Close', the for keeps running through the rest of the list

using 'exit for', 'exit sub', 'return' isn't exactly what i need, because after the for/sub there's more code i need to NOT RUN.

example code:

```
Private Sub form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AnyMethod()
    Msgbox("This message (1) isn't supposed to show AT ALL, yet it does")
End Sub

Private Sub AnyMethod()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        If i = 4 Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
        Msgbox("This message (2) is supposed to show only four times")
    Next
    Msgbox("This message (3) isn't supposed to show AT ALL, yet it does")
End Sub
```

Comment: add a return after the close.

Comment: Close() just closes the window, it does *not* abort code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rest of the event handler is executed because you did not leave the method. It is as simple as that. You can leave the method with `Exit Sub` after the `Me.Close()`

Calling `Me.Close()` does not immediately "delete" the form (and the current event handler). The form will be collected later on by the garbage collector if there are no more references to the form.

Additionally the `Closed` event will be called.

`Me.Close()` is nothing than a regular method call, and unless the method throws an exception you will stay in the context of your current method.

If you don't want to display message 1 you should return a value from `AnyMethod`.

```
Private Sub form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If (AnyMethod()) Then
       Exit Sub
    End If
    Msgbox("This message (1) isn't supposed to show AT ALL, yet it does")
End Sub

Private Function AnyMethod() as Boolean
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        If i = 4 Then
            Me.Close()
            Return True
        End If
        Msgbox("This message (2) is supposed to show only four times")
    Next
    Msgbox("This message (3) isn't supposed to show AT ALL, yet it does")
    Return False
End Sub
```

Comment: the return works exactly as a 'exit sub', however the 1st msgbox still runs....

thanks anyway

Comment: You are right @ViníciusKaiser Didn't use VB.Net for a long time. :-)

Comment: @ViníciusKaiser Did you add the `If` statement to the `Form2_Load` method as shown in this answer?

Comment: @AndrewMorton at the time of my first comment, i didnt see the 'if' statement.. and for the example code it solved the problem... however, the actual code is not running in the 'load' event and the method is called from another method, wich is called from another method, and it only stops the execution of the last method...
however i already solved my problem with a similar solution.. i created a boolean as false and i set it to true along with the 'close' method, and i test it in the rest of the code... thanks guys